# checking text visibility with jquery .contains code not behaving as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I have a form that dynamically displays an error message "This is a required question" whenever a required field is left empty when the submit button is clicked.   I want to see if that error message is visible on the webpage. If so, I should display an alert box with the message, "Found errors in the form, please correct them!". If not, then I can go ahead and process the form. I am using jquery for this. Here is the problem: I filled out the form without any errors and when I clicked on the submit button it still pops up the alert box. Is my code correct?

```js
if ($('div:contains(This is a required question)').is(':visible')) {

     alert('Found errors in the form, please correct them!');

} else {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(Success).withFailureHandler(failed).processForm();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) accept a string, you need to pass it in quotes.

So use,

```
 $('div:contains("This is a required question")')
```

*Complete Code*

```
if ($('div:contains("This is a required question")').is(':visible')) {
    alert('Found errors in the form, please correct them!');
} else {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(Success).withFailureHandler(failed).processForm();
}
```

Comment: The alert box is still popping up even with your code.

Comment: @Helix check if the messages are in a div or other tag like span etc.

Comment: @Pugazh I can't post my html code here as it is too long.

Comment: @Helix, You can use JSFiddle

Comment: @Helix can you confirm if there is no text in the div then div is **hidden**.

Comment: `if ($('div:contains("This is a required question")').length) {` you can try with this too.

Comment: @Jai There is text in the div and the alert box is still popping up even with your code.

Comment: Btw, I am using the following google's jquery CDN link: https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js